# NS button text interprets FontAwesome

Tags: nativescript

If I set the text of the Button whose font is FontAwesome to something like "Download" - it interprets 'down' as an font from FA as well as 'ad'

e.g. Open = it'll display O and then a pen icon from FA.

Very weird - how can I stop this.

I'd like the button text to contain both FA icons (specified with unicode escape codes) and regular text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used FontAwesome recently, I recall they use to denote icons by character code so there were no issues in combining text along with icons, not sure if that's changed now.

As a workaround you can use `formattedText` instead of `text`. You will be able to use different fonts within `Button` with 2 different `FormattedString` definitions, one for icon and another for text.

Comment: Thanks - that's a good workaround. Odd feature to translate parts of words into icons. Who needs that?